# A plane is colored with three colors. Prove that there exists a right triangle on this plane, having vertices of the same color.

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I got stuck with this idea in mind that I could find a shape with all of the vertices connected to each other and all of its angles being 90 degrees. One of such shapes **which is not correct** is as follows.

[image]

But, as you can see, it does not work. **What is your suggested manner... shape?**

Comment: I cant understand the relation between the title of your question and the question you post  !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the colors $1,2,3$. We can always find two points that have the same color, say $p_1$ and $p_2$ are both colored $1$. Define $p_m$ to be the midpoint of $p_1p_2$. There are two cases:

Case 1: If $p_m$ has color $1$. Then draw three parallel lines $l_1, l_2, l_m$ through the points $p_1,p_2, p_m$, each perpendicular to $p_1p_2$. If any point on $l_1,l_2,l_m$ besides $p_1,p_2,p_m$ has color $1$ we are done. So suppose that every point on $l_1, l_2, l_m$ besides $p_1,p_2,p_m$ has color $2$ or $3$. Choose two points with the same color on $l_1$, call them $q_1,q_2$ and say they are both colored $2$. If we draw lines through $q_1$ and $q_2$ perpendicular to $l_1$, we get $4$ intersection points with lines $l_2, l_m$. If any intersection point has color $2$, we have a monochromatic right triangle with $q_1$ and $q_2$, and if all of the intersetction points are color $3$, they form a monochromatic rectangle, which includes a right triangle. So, every outcome includes a monochromatic right triangle.

Case 2: If $p_m$ has color different from $1$, say $2$. Draw a circle centered at $p_m$ through $p_1$. If any point on the circle other than $p_1$ and $p_2$ has color $1$, it forms a monochromatic right triangle with $p_1$ and $p_2$ and we're done. So suppose every point on the circle except for $p_1$ and $p_2$ has color $2$ or $3$. Take a pair of diameters of the circle at right angles to each other (avoiding the diameter $p_1p_2$). If $3$ or more of the endpoints are color $3$, we are done, so we can assume that at least $2$ of the endpoints have color $2$. If they are antipodal, then with $p_m$, we are back in Case $1$ and if they are not antipodal, they form a monochromatic right triangle with $p_m$.

In every case we find a monochromatic right triangle.

Comment: Thanks for the cool solution, but... How the bloody hell did you come across this solution?! Had you already worked out the same or similar problems?

Comment: @Mill I started off thinking of Thales' theorem - finding a monochromatic right triangle is equivalent to finding a circle with where the endpoints of a diameter and another point have the same color. That immediately reduces the problem to 2 colors on the remainder of the circle, and indicates that the center of the circle could be useful. Then, looking at other diameters seemed like a good idea. It only took a little thought to realize that the only remaining case was three monochromatic points in a line - that ended up being Case 1, while the circle became Case 2.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of how you got here. Thales' Theorem was the key point and I had missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Denote any line segment with end points of color x and y as (x,y).
Consider an (r,r). Draw a line perpendicular to it at each end point (l1 and l2). We consider the set A of all line segments between these two lines. Any line of set A can't be (b,b) or (g,g) as then all other points of l1 and l2 will be g or b and we will be done. Any point of l1 and l2 can't be r either. Consider 3 lines from set A. They must be either (b,g) or (g,b). So there are two of a kind(say (b,g)). Extend those line segments(l3 and l4). All other points of l3 and l4 must be r and we are done.