# Existence of a Right angled triangle in a two coloured plane

Tags: triangles, combinatorial-geometry

Suppose the 2-d plane is coloured in two colours. You are given a right angled triangle of given dimensions. Prove that there exists a monochromatic copy(i.e the vertices are of same colour) of the given triangle on the plane.

Comment: Your plane is restricted to points with **integer coordinates**, isn't it ?

Comment: It's R^2 probably.

Comment: Tough to do with integer coordinates if your right-angled triangle has a side of non-surd length.

Comment: No the plane is not restricted to integer coordinates.

Comment: Connected [same problem with 3 colors](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1508249)

Comment: One thing again: you should say that it is only the vertices of the triangle that should be with a same color (monochromatic).